# php mysql refresh dynamic page after form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to figure out how to refresh a page after a form is submitted which updates a column in my db ... the user pushes a button in a notification area and it updates the sql db ... as this area is located site wide, i don't want to send them to a specific page as they might not be on that page ... since all of the pages are dynamically generated, using $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] responds with .com/page.php rather than .com/page.php?user_id=1.

is there a way to get refresh with the dynamic page extension? as always, any and all help is greatly appreciated!! thanks!!

Comment: just use javascript to set your action with the query parameter included

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`

For example:

```
$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
```

Will return the full url path, Not just the self script path.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: why was this down voted? this was the correct answer ... thanks @epik ... worked exactly how i needed it to!

Comment: Glad to hear. Please mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't provide a action attribute in the form element, that way the form is submitted to the current page, e.g .com/page.php?user_id=1